# Correspondence between ideals of Lie algebra and connected normal subgroups of connected algebraic group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, connectedness, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a connected linear algebraic group (LAG) and $H\leq G$ a closed connected subgroup such that $\operatorname{Lie}H\subseteq\operatorname{Lie}G$ is an ideal. I want to show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

To do so the main result I have is :

1. For $\phi,\psi:G\to H$ morphisms of LAG, then : $(d\phi)_e=(d\psi)_e\implies \phi=\psi$
2. If $H_1,H_2\leq G$ are closed, $\operatorname{Lie}(H_1\cap H_2)=\operatorname{Lie}H_2\cap\operatorname{Lie}H_2$, in particular $\operatorname{Lie}H_1=\operatorname{Lie}H_2\implies H_1^{o}=H_2^{o}$ (connected components)
3. For $\phi:G\to H$, $H'\leq H$ closed, we have that $\operatorname{Lie}(\phi(G))=(d\phi)_e(\operatorname{Lie}G)$ and $\operatorname{Lie}(\phi^{-1}(H'))=(d\phi)_e^{-1}(\operatorname{Lie}H')$. In particular $\operatorname{Lie}(\operatorname{Ker}\phi)=\operatorname{Ker}((d\phi)_e)$.

So my idea is to consider $\phi_g:H\to G$ the conjugation by $g$ and show that $\operatorname{Lie}H=\operatorname{Lie}\phi_g(H)$ which would lead to $H=\phi_g(H)$ since they are connected. We have $\operatorname{Lie}(\phi_g(H))=(d\phi_g)_e(\operatorname{Lie}H)$ and I want to show its equal to $\operatorname{Lie}H$. But $(d\phi_g)_e:\operatorname{Lie}H\to\operatorname{Lie}G$ is defined by $A\mapsto A\circ \phi_g^*$ where $\phi_g^*:\mathcal O(G)\to \mathcal O(H)$ is the induced algebra morphism between coordinate rings.  From this I'm not sure on how to proceed to show that the image of this map is in $\operatorname{Lie}H$.

Am I on the right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G$ be a smooth connected (affine) algebraic group over some ground field $k$ and write $\mathfrak{g}$ for its Lie algebra.
As was already pointed out in Armado's answer, we have the adjoint representation of $G$
$$\operatorname{Ad} \colon G \to \operatorname{GL}_{\mathfrak{g}}$$
and its derivative
$$\operatorname{ad} = d(\operatorname{Ad}) \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{gl}_{\mathfrak{g}}$$
and the Lie bracket on $\mathfrak{g}$ is basically defined by $[x, y] = \operatorname{ad}(x)(y)$.

Now suppose we are given a smooth connected algebraic subgroup $H \subseteq G$ such that its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ is an ideal in $\mathfrak{g}$.
Then we claim that $H \subseteq G$ is actually normal.
To prove this we proceed in two steps:

- Consider the algebraic subgroup $P \subseteq \operatorname{GL}_{\mathfrak{g}}$ given as the stabilizer of the subspace $\mathfrak{h} \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$.
  Its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq \mathfrak{gl}_{\mathfrak{g}}$ is then given as the set of those endomorphisms of $\mathfrak{g}$ that stabilize $\mathfrak{h}$.
  The condition that $\mathfrak{h} \subseteq \mathfrak{g}$ is an ideal thus translates into saying that $\operatorname{ad}(\mathfrak{g}) \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$, which implies that $\operatorname{Ad}(G) \subseteq P$.
- Now suppose that $g \in G(k)$ and consider the conjugation map $\phi_g \colon G \to G$.
  By definition of the adjoint representation we have $\operatorname{Ad}(g) = d(\phi_g)$.
  Thus the previous bullet point implies that $d(\phi_g)(\mathfrak{h}) \subseteq \mathfrak{h}$ which implies that $\phi_g(H) \subseteq H$.
  As $g \in G(k)$ was arbitrary, this shows that $H \subseteq G$ is normal.

Answer (score -1):

Given the representation of Lie groups induced by the conjugation:

$\text{Ad}:G \rightarrow \text{GL}(\text{Lie}(G))$,

we can differentiate it and obtain:

$d(\text{Ad}):\text{Lie}(G) \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}( \text{Lie}(G))$

It is easy to see that this map is extacly the $\text{ad}$ of Lie algebras (to compute this remember that $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} e^{tX}=X $).

So by the universal property of the differential we obtain that $\text{Ad}(e^X)=e^{\text{ad}(X)}$ $\forall X \in \text{Lie}(G)$.

Since $G$ is connected it is generated by $\text{exp}(\text{Lie}(G))$ so a generic $g\in G$ is of the form $e^{X_1}…e^{X_t}$, we can assume $g=e^X$ (the computation is similar).

We can now see that $\text{Ad}(g)(H)\subseteq H$, let $h \in H$:

$\text{Ad}(e^X)(h)=e^{\text{ad}(X)}(h)=\sum_n \frac{\text{ad}(X)^n}{n!} (h) $,

now since also $h$ is of the form $h=e^{Y}=\sum_m \frac{Y^m}{m!}$ and since $\text{Lie}(H)$ is and ideal of $\text{Lie}(G)$ we can easily conclude the proof.

Comment: Thank you @Armando however this does not use anything I've stated earlier. I'm well aware that proofs exist using the exponential map, however in my course we didn't define it. Also note that I haven't talked about Lie groups, I don't suppose they have a structure of manifolds.